# ExpressJS / Mongoose res.send() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have multiple callbacks before and then I want to do a res.send() to build JSON API:

```
app.get('/api', function (req, res){
...
        function logPagesId() {
            console.log("load: " +pagesId);
            console.log("lenght: " +pagesId.length);
            findWords(logWords);
        }

        function logWords() {
           console.log("TAGS: "+wordsArray);
           return res.send(wordsArray);
        }

    findIdPages(logPagesId);
}
```

In the log, I have:

```
Successfully connected to MongoDB
load: 45678bdhbdns768,45678bdhbdns765
lenght: 2
TAGS:
{ _id: 45678bdhbdns765,
  result:
   { ID1: { Pages: [Object], Name: [Object] },
     ID2: { Pages: [Object], Name: [Object] },
    ....
```

At the end, it returns [].

[EDIT]

[FULL CODE]

```
app.get('/tags/reference/:reference', function (req, res){
    var articlesId = [];
    var tagsArray = [];
  function findIdArticles(callback) {
      Articles.find({reference: req.params.reference}, '_id' , function (err, articles) {
      if (!err) {
        for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
            articlesId.push(articles[i]._id);
        }
        for (i=0 ; i < articlesId.length; i++){
            Extract_Tags.findById(articlesId[i], function (err, tags) {
            if (!err) {
                tagsArray.push(tags);
                console.log(tags);
                callback(null, tagsArray);
            } else {
                callback(err);
            }
            });
        }

    } else {
      callback(err);
    }
    });
  }

     function logArticlesId(err, response) {
        res.status(503).send('fancy server side error message!');
        console.log("load: " +articlesId);
        console.log("tagsArray: " +tagsArray);
        console.log("response: " +response);
        logTags(response);
     }

    function logTags(response) {
        console.log("TAGS: "+response);
        res.send(response);

    }

findIdArticles(logArticlesId);
});
```

Here is the full code with some changes. Just have the error fancy server side error message!
Thanks for your hel

Comment: What does not work as expected? What have you tried to fix the issue? What version of express are you using? What are the thrown errors? So many questions, so little information. -1

Comment: It sould return a JSON but it returns an empty array []. If I do something simple, res.send() works. But as I use a function in a function I think there is somehting wrong.

Comment: You messed up. Where is Your findIdPages function and what it does?

Comment: You should use `res.json()` if you're wanting to send back JSON.

Comment: @Jarema findIdPages just return a value with a callback. The thing is I can see the data (in the log) that I want to display as an API.

Comment: @mscdex thanks! well for the moment I just want some info back.

Comment: You dont show us that callback in Your example, so its hard to help. res.json() i guess is not full solution.

Comment: @Jarema Just edited. I added the function with the callback.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Your callback functions should always return - even if there is error. Otherwise Your callback function in error scenario will never be called!

So, for findIdArticles()

```
function findIdArticles(callback) {
      Articles.find({folder: req.params.folder}, '_id' , function (err, articles) {
      if (!err) {
      for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
        pagesId.push(pages[i]._id);
       }
        callback(null, pagesId);
    } else {
        callback(err);
    }
    });
  }
```

secondly You call `findIdPages` and You showed us `findIdArticles`

when those mistakes are resolved, Your `app.get` should look like this:

```
app.get('/api', function (req, res){
...
        function logPagesId(err, response) {
            // deal with errors, for ie:
             if (err) {
                res.status(503).send('fancy server side error message!');
                return;
            }


            console.log("load: " +response);
            console.log("lenght: " +response.length);
            findWords(response);
        }

        function logWords() {
           console.log("TAGS: "+wordsArray);
           return res.send(wordsArray);
        }

    findIdPages(logPagesId);
}
```

but it STILL will not help, as You never call logWords here. I guess  its in findWords, which need similar work. that i've done to existing functions.

**EDIT** there was error in my answer. please check now.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just edited the code with your changes but still have an error. Thanks!

Comment: does this line:

console.log("TAGS: "+response);

output proper data?

Comment: Yes, I got the data into response. but then it doesn't work res.send(response); I think it is because of for (i=0 ; i < articlesId.length; i++){
            Extract_Tags.findById(articlesId[i], function (err, tags) {
            if (!err) {
                tagsArray.push(tags);
                console.log(tags);
                callback(null, tagsArray);
            } else {
                callback(err);
            }
            });
        }

Comment: I have the following error 
http.js:689
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)

Comment: there was error in my code (res.status(502) was sent always, not only if error occurs). please recheck :)